Pyreverse inserting linebreaks for too long UML Diagrams
The PyReverse generated diagram shows a very large class. I think this issue primarily arises because there are no line breaks in the methods block (see the bottom row):

How can I insert line breaks within method names?
I think there is no options to solve this problem in pyreverse, but I want to be sure.
See: https://gist.github.com/HarshaVardhanBabu/9a47db9e33cf06e9e1e917520bb54056
